# Querying fields with AND in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

In my ElasticSearch document index I have a property `type` like

```
type= LOCATION | PERSON | TIME
```

and a `text` field that represents the whole document.

To search for types like `LOCATION` and a specific text like `Mountain View" I do like

`doc.text:Mountain View AND doc.type:LOCATION`

If I want to do a `OR` query I would use instead the `query_string` approach like

```
"query": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "entity.text: (Mountain View OR Menlo Park) AND entity.type:LOCATION"
                        }
                    }
```

This works as well. To do `AND` queries, like searching for `item.text` having both "Mountain View" and "Menlo Park" for a `item.type=LOCATION`, it does not work doing like

```
"query": {
                        "query_string": {
                            "query": "entity.text: (California AND Nevada) AND entity.type:LOCATION"
                        }
                    }
```

Other attempts were:

Using `bool` clause with `should` like:

```
{
                    "query": {
                      "bool": {
                        "should": [
                          { "match": { "text": "Menlo Park" }},
                          { "match": { "text": "Mountain View" }}
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

Using `cross-fields` with `multi_match`

```
"query": {
                      "multi_match": {
                        "query": "California Nevada",
                        "type": "cross_fields",
                        "operator": "AND",
                        "fields": [
                          "text"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
```

Another approach was using `must` with the latter (in this case omitting the `type` by the way):

```
{
                    "query": {
                      "bool": {
                        "must": [
                          {
                            "multi_match" : {
                              "query":      "Nevada",
                              "type":       "cross_fields",
                              "fields":     [ "text"],
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "multi_match" : {
                              "query":      "California",
                              "type":       "cross_fields",
                              "fields":     [ "text" ]
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
```

but it returns no results neither. Note that in the last case using `should` instead of `must` will produce an `OR` query that will work ok.

So how to perform an `AND` query on the same field `text` to match multiple values like `California` and `Nevada`?

Comment: so, what is your question?

Comment: @christouandr7 I was updating the question right now, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that the results must have California and Nevada on the text?

Comment: @christouandr7 yes exactly.

Comment: check my answer! hope it is what you are looking for!

Comment: @christouandr7 thank you let me have try.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question right, I would do the following:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
           "must": [
             "match" : {
              "text" : {
                "query" : "California Nevada",
                "operator" : "and"
               }
             }
           ]
        }
    }
}
```

[Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html)
Hope it helps!